# 2 OrderedDictionarys multiplying the two values, multiple keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two OrderedDicts:

```
A = OrderedDict([(('a', 'b'), 4) ... ])    
B = OrderedDict([('b', 2) ... ])
```

What is the best way to multiply the two values given that the `'b'` in `A` is the same as the key in `B`?

I am struggling with the fact that there are two keys in `A`.

Expected output:

```
C = ([('a', 'b') 8) ... ])
```

Just to be clear, I am looking for a match between the key in `B` and the second half of the tuple `A`'s key. If they are equal to each other then I want to multiply the two `.values()` in their respective elements.

Here is my (feeble) attempt:

```
for a in A.keys():
    print a
    for b, c in A.keys():
        print c # this prints the second tuple in A
```

Im not quite sure how to pass this to `B.keys()` and multiple the matching `values()`

Comment: Those are lists, not dictionaries.

Comment: So `A` is a OrderedDictionary and the keys are tuples?

Comment: Can you give an example input and desired output?

Comment: output is mentioned above. let me know if you would like more information

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Also what order do you wish to retain in `C`?

Comment: I have updated with my attempt. C should contain the tuple shown in A with the new computed value. General order of the list should ideally be sorted on the new value()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 methods. Do these do what you want? They result in a dict though not an ordered dict. You could pass the dict to `OrderedDict` but the order would not be well defined.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

A = OrderedDict({('a','b'): 4, ('b','a'): 5, ('b','c'): 2, ('a','c'): 6})
B = OrderedDict({'b': 2, 'c' : 5})

''' Method 1 quadratic '''
C = {}
for bk, bv in B.items():
    for ak, av in A.items():
        if bk == ak[1]:
            C[ak] = bv * av

print(C)

''' Method 2 linear '''
D = {}
for ak, av in A.items():
    if ak[1] in B:
        D[ak] = av * B[ak[1]]

print(D)

''' Method 3 linear one-liner '''
E = {ak: av * B[ak[1]] for ak, av in A.items() if ak[1] in B}

print(E)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> A = {('a', 'b'): 4}
>>> B = {'b': 2}

>>> C = {key: (value * B[key[1]])
...      for key, value in A.items()}

>>> C
{('a', 'b'): 8}
```

Comment: Well, I don't think this is OP wants since OP said *the `'b'` in `A` is the same as the key in `B`*. I don't understand what does OP mean, but I think it *means something special.*

Comment: @Peter Wood, how would I use 'value' in this instance? A.value() ?

Comment: sorry, fixed, I missed getting the value from `A`